# Installing Talend Open Studio Mac Os Sonoma

Tags: installation, jvm, talend, macos-sonoma

I'm trying to install TOS on my Mac running on Sonoma.
After the installation i have this message :

The JVM shared library "/Users/aetox/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-20.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"

does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

I tried to change the root in info.plist :

-vm/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-20.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/java

Nothing works...

Comment: That version of MacOS is not supported: https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/installation-guide-windows/software-requirements

Comment: This worked for me: https://www.reddit.com/r/Talend/comments/16v83k2/solvedinstallation_of_tos_801_on_mac_os_m2_pro/